# android enabling the default back button in the menubar

Tags: menu

I want to enable default android back button, I use

```
getActionbar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in my application but the back function not working, I use fragment transaction to replace fragment in my activity, I used addtoBackStack() also, my device back button is working, but the android default back button is not working in my application.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't finish your activity on click of the help menu. Once you call finish, the activity will be destroyed and removed from the activity stack (so when you press back, it's no longer the previous activity).

You should only finish the activity when it is truly done (i.e. the user has completed whatever it is that the activity was supposed to let them do). You need to think of the set of activities in your application as a stack. Each time you start an activity, it is placed at the top of the stack. If you want the back button to take you back to the previous activity, don't finish it (since each time you call finish it removes it from the stack). Every time the user presses back, the current activity is "popped" from the stack and the system resumes the activity below it. If there are no more activities from your app on the stack when the user presses back, your app is finished and the user goes back to the home screen.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.i use only one activity to replace 4 fragments i attach my code

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);if(savedInstanceState==null){
MystoreFragment mystore=new MystoreFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.mystoreContainer,mystore,"MyStore");OtherStoreFragment otherStore=new OtherStoreFragment();getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.otherStoreContainer,otherStore,"OtherStore").commit();

Comment: public void moreClicked(MyStoreList myStoreList) {
StoreFragment fragment=new StoreFragment(); fragment.setArguments(arg);FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentl, fragment);OfferFragment offer=new OfferFragment();offer.setArguments(arg);transaction.replace(R.id.mystoreContainer, offer);TransactionFragment transactionFragment=new TransactionFragment();transactionFragment.setArguments(arg);transaction.replace(R.id.otherStoreContainer, transactionFragment); transaction.addToBackStack(null);transaction.commit();}

Comment: I added `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` on the second activity but when I press it it doesn't take me to the previous activity. How do I fix it?